# Calling C functions on Python prints only the first character

Tags: python, c

I tried to call c function in python here is my code

string.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int print(const char *str)
{
  printf("%s", str):
  return 0;
}
```

string.py

```
from ctypes import *
so_print = "/home/ubuntu/string.so"
my_functions = CDLL(so_print)
print(my_functions.print("hello"))
```

when i run the python script it prints only the fist character of the string
example "h"

How can i pass any string and my c code will read and display it.

Answer (score 4):

Your function accepts a `const char*`, which corresponds to a Python `bytes` object (which [coerces to `c_char_p`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types)), not a `str` (which coerces to `c_wchar_p`). You didn't tell Python what the underlying C function's prototype was, so it just converted your `str` to a `c_wchar_p`, and UTF-16 or UTF-32 encoded string with solely ASCII characters *looks* like either an empty or single character (depending on platform endianness) C-style `char *` string.

Two things to improve:

1. Define [the prototype for `print` so Python can warn you when you misuse it, adding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes):

   ```
   my_functions.print.argtypes = [c_char_p]
   ```

   before using the function.
2. Encode `str` arguments to `bytes` so they can be converted to valid C-style `char*` strings:

   ```
   # For arbitrary string, just encode:
   print(my_functions.print(mystr.encode()))

   # For a literal, you can pass a bytes literal
   print(my_functions.print(b"hello"))
                          # ^ b makes it a bytes, not str
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the following change here.

- Pass byteobject instead of string.

This because of as per the [Fundamental data types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) `c_char_p` in `c` is python 's byte object equivalent type

```
from ctypes import *
so_print = "string.so"
my_functions = CDLL(so_print)
print(my_functions.print(b"hello"))
```